# How can I send the output of a Logger object in python to a file?

Tags: python, file, logging

I am using the **logging** library in python. I am using several **logger** objects to output the information. I got to the point where the output is too much, and I need to send it to a logfile instead of the console.
I can't find a function that configures the output stream of the logger object, and the **basicConf** function doesn't seem to do the trick.
This is what I have:

```
import logging # Debug logging framework
logging.basicConfig(filename='loggggggmeee.txt')
logger = logging.getLogger('simulation')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

#--------------- etc-------------------#

logger.info('This is sent to the console')
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add a file location like here it will solve your problem:

```
import logging # Debug logging framework
logging.basicConfig(filename='c:\\loggggggmeee.txt')
logger = logging.getLogger('simulation')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

#--------------- etc-------------------#

logger.info('This is sent to the console')
```

By the way the file without a specific location will be at the module library...

I really recommend you to read the [Logging HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#) It's very simple and useful.

Also the [Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook) has lots of useful examples.

Another good tip about nameing the loggers from the docs:

> a good convention to use when naming loggers is to use a module-level
>   logger, in each module which uses logging, named as follows:
>
> ```
> logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
> ```
>
> This means that logger names
>   track the package/module hierarchy, and it’s intuitively obvious where
>   events are logged just from the logger name.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had looked at the HOWTO and I couldn't find that specific information. I had not discovered the Cookbook, but I see the examples are very useful.